# Passing the file location from command line

Tags: command-line, vbscript, arguments, email-attachments

Below is my VBScript code to send an email with a file attached. The file is present at a location which I need to grab when sending the email.

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set arg1 = args.Item(0)
objMessage.Subject = "Sample subject" 
objMessage.From = "test@gmail.com" 
objMessage.To = "test2@gmail.com" 
objMessage.TextBody = "Please see the error logs attached with this email"
objMessage.AddAttachment ""&arg1&""
'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
'==Normally you will only change the server name or IP.
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "hostname"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
```

To run this script through command line I use:

```
>cscript sendemail.vbs D:\users\me\Desktop\readme.txt
```

When I run this I get an error saying:

> D:\Users\me\Desktop\sendemail.vbs(3, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: '[string: "D:\Users\me\Desk"]'

Any suggestions what could be wrong with this?

Comment: You should be able to just use `objMessage.AddAttachment args(0)`

Comment: I tried what you said, but it gives me the same exact error.

Comment: that is strange. That is how I do all my emails with vbscript. I use a generic vbscript where I pass everything as arguments to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message actually says it all. While the `Arguments` collection is an object, its first element is not. It's a string, which in VBScript is a primitive data type. The `Set` keyword is exclusively for assigning objects to variables. Primitive data types are assigned by just using the assignment operator.

Change this:

```
Set arg1 = args.Item(0)
```

into this:

```
arg1 = args.Item(0)
```

and the error will disappear.